# Launch host app from watch app

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

I know that the `openParentApplication` api in watch kit extension can open the host app in the background but not in the foreground.

I also tried using `openUrl()` api of `NSExtensionContext` as below:

```
NSExtensionContext *ctx = [[NSExtensionContext alloc] init];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myScheme://today"];
[ctx openURL:url completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    NSLog(@"fun=%s after completion. success=%d", __func__, success);
}];
[ctx completeRequestReturningItems:ctx.inputItems completionHandler:nil];
```

Here too the host app is not launched. Am I missing something? or is it not possible to
launch the host app from watch kit extension?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**If you need to open your parent app in the foreground, use Handoff!**

**https://developer.apple.com/handoff/**

**Example**:

Somewhere shared for both:

```
static let sharedUserActivityType = "com.yourcompany.yourapp.youraction"
static let sharedIdentifierKey = "identifier"
```

on your Watch:

```
updateUserActivity(sharedUserActivityType, userInfo: [sharedIdentifierKey : 123456], webpageURL: nil)
```

on your iPhone in App Delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, willContinueUserActivityWithType userActivityType: String) -> Bool {
    if (userActivityType == sharedUserActivityType) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]!) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if (userActivity.activityType == sharedUserActivityType) {
        if let userInfo = userActivity.userInfo as? [String : AnyObject] {
            if let identifier = userInfo[sharedIdentifierKey] as? Int {
                //Do something
                let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Handoff", message: "Handoff has been triggered for identifier \(identifier)" , delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Thanks for the info!")
                alert.show()
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

**And finally (this step is important!!!): In your Info.plist(s)**

[image]

Comment: Is this code shows the alert which you have mentioned??

Comment: No Sir it is not showing for me. Can you please help me on this? And also will this code will bring the app from background to foreground??

Comment: Will WatchOS apps using these code be approved by the App Store?

Answer (score 22):

As of Beta 3 of iOS 8.2 it is currently not possible to open iOS app to foreground.
As you said `openParentApplication` can open app in background. Unfortunately there is no sign of API to open app on iPhone.

Multiple posts on Apple Dev Forums mentioned that it's not possible

https://devforums.apple.com/message/1076125#1076125

> Correct, a notification can still declare a background action that the iPhone app will handle, so in that sense it can launch the iPhone app. But the iPhone app cannot be brought to the foreground by a WatchKit app.

And other post

https://devforums.apple.com/message/1082620#1082620

> On a device, it[Watch app] will not -  bring your iOS app to the foreground.

Comment: Thanks for remembering me the Apple Developer forum. It was a place forgotten for long time. You deserve 50 reps.

Comment: Is it possible to detect if the host/main app is already opened and in foreground?

Answer (score 12):

I'm hopeful that Apple will provide API for launching the parent app from a watch app in a future beta, but for now I've managed to achieve it by doing the following...

Call `openParentApplication:reply:` as normal:

```
- (void)openPhoneApp {
    [WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:[NSDictionary new] reply:nil];
}
```

Implement `application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:` in your AppDelegate, and launch itself using a custom URL scheme:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myappscheme://open"]];
}
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I tried the same code from extensions but was not supported there. Will the app be approved?? Is this legal?

Comment: I'm not sure whether Apple would approve this.  I can't see why not because as far as I can tell it doesn't break any rules.  This is only a temporary workaround anyway, I'm hoping that Apple will provide an official way to do this in a future beta.

Comment: While this approach does launch the parent iOS app in the foreground in the simulator, I have verified with Apple twice that this functionality will not be allowed in the App Store. This answer is not correct and should not be used. @Ivp has the correct answer here.

Comment: @cnoon won't it be allowed even from a WatchKit app? Is there an alternative way?