# Can a watchOS 2 app launch another app?

Tags: ios, watchos-2

I have 2 iOS apps that have watchOS 2 extensions. If a user is using the first app, it sometimes makes sense for them to want to launch into the second app. In iOS you can do this using openURL:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];
```

But I can not find an equivalent on watchOS 2. Does anyone know of a way to have a watchOS 2 app launch another app?

Comment: If you combined ideas from these two posts then wouldn't it help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123194/how-to-use-uiapplication-sharedapplication-openurl-open-other-app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700907/launch-host-app-from-watch-app

Comment: Unfortunately, those posts are about launching the Apple Watch's parent app. Those API's won't work to try to launch a different app on the watch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, You can't.

---

You can launch only system apps in watchOS using [[WKExtension openSystemURL:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKExtension_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKExtension/openSystemURL:).
(Some system URLs may works on only iOS)

There is no API for 3rd party scheme.